# How to force spring to use the same i18n Locale for every user

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internationalization

I'm developing a Java Spring application which will be used in different countries. In each country, it has to "speak" the country's language (not the user's country). 
With speak I mean that the messages at jsp pages (), javax.validation messages, etc. 
Right now, I have different properties files for each country. For example, ApplicationResources_ES.properties, ApplicationResources_EN.properties, ValidationMessages_ES.properties, ValidationMessages_EN.properties, etc.

I'm not able to force spring to use just ES or EN language, no matter which the user's language is. 
I've tried with fixedLocaleResolver with no sucessfully results using:

```
<bean id="fixedLocaleResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
</bean>
```

Anyone can help me?

**Update:**
This is a more specific problem which I want to solve. 
I have a ValidationMessages.properties for every language to show the result of javax.validation in the language of the application installation. The problem is that the language is changing depending on the user's locale, not the application locale. How could I make that javax.validation uses one of the ValidationMessages.properties, without changing it dinamically depending on the users?

Answer (score 1):

Your bean must have the name `localeResolver` so that `DispatcherServlet` is able to load the localeResolver. So change `id` as below:

```
<bean id="localeResolver" c...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution but I don't really like it.
If I change the default country and language for the user when launching tomcat with this properties:

```
-Duser.language=pt -Duser.country=PT
```

Then, the validation messages of javax.validation are shown in portuguese. I should change this property for each installation. However, I don't think this is a clean solution. Anyone has any other one?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the `setLocale` method of `FixedLocaleResolver`?

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/FixedLocaleResolver.html#FixedLocaleResolver(java.util.Locale)

Comment: I don't know if this could be a help for me. This method needs a requets and a response, doesn't it? I just want to set the locale for my entire application. For instance, when I'm showing the validation errors thrown by javax.validation, I want them to be in my default language (not the user's language). Could you explain a little bit more how should I use the setLocale method?

Comment: Also, when I setLocale in one of my controllers, it throws this exception:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot change fixed locale - use a different locale resolution strategy